# AngularJS and Rails - posts by category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a Rails app that gets posts by category using `show` action.

The route is: `/categories/:id(.:format)      categories#show`

The `.json` also render the posts of the given category because I modified `as_json`method to include posts.

As of the AngularJS part, I'm using `ui-router` and `angular-rails-templates` and I have:

Service:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'templates']);

app.factory('categories', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        categories: []
    };
    o.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/category/' + id + '.json').then(
            function(res){ return res.data; }
        );
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller(
    'CategoriesCtrl',
    [
        '$scope',
        'categories',
        'category',
        function($scope, categories, category) {
            $scope.category = category; //just for testing purposes
        }
    ]
);
```

Configuration

```
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state(
            'category',
            {
                url: '/category/:categoryId',
                templateUrl: 'categories/_categories.html',
                controller: 'CategoriesCtrl'
            }
        );
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
]);
```

I don't understand what is wrong. The log is `"Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'categories' must return a value from $get factory method.` What it suppose to return and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to return the `o` object from the factory, it should be:

```
app.factory('categories', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var o = {
        categories: []
    };
    o.get = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/category/' + id + '.json').then(function (res) {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    // You missed this
    return o;
}]);
```